# Make an exact replica of a view (excluding data) in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

Is there a way to make an exact replica of a View in Google Analytics?

Based on the documentation here (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3256366?hl=en&fbclid=IwAR2_5523Iz89Be8P6wkXxMla5BiS9NL4DLrzVuJ1ib23WvuDwzq4idnGBa4).

> Settings and features controlled at the view level (like filters,
> Goals, users and their permissions) are duplicated in copied views.
> Cost source links and shared assets (like annotations, Segments, and
> alerts) are not duplicated into copied views.

It seems like many items don't get copied across. I also noted that calculated metrics and custom reports are also not copied across.

Is there a way to create an exact replica (excluding the data)?